# Image Button to open phone galllery and display picture on Android

Tags: android, imagebutton

I tried looking for code that would help me with selecting a picture from my phone's gallery to the image button in my application, however, most of it is with an Image View.

I was wondering if somebody could help me by showing me how to do this please?

Comment: ImageView is no different than an ImageButton, so where is the code you tried or errors you're getting?

Comment: I haven't tried because I dont know what to do or where to start to be honest @cricket_007

Comment: Make a layout? Find a view? Attach a click listener? Find the probably answered question on Stackoverflow about how to open the Gallery to get a picture... Etc

Answer (score 0):

First in your xml create ImageButton:

```
<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/image_button"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:scaleType="fitCenter"/>
```

Then in your activity:

1. Create class variable:

   ```
   ImageButton imageButton;
   ```
2. In OnCreate method find this button and set OnClickListener:

   ```
   imageButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.image_button);
   imageButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
       @Override
       public void onClick(View v) {
           Intent photoPickerIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
           photoPickerIntent.setType("image/*");
           startActivityForResult(photoPickerIntent, 500);
       }
   });
   ```
3. Override onActivityResult:

   ```
   @Override
   public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
   super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

   switch(requestCode) {
       case 500:
           if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){
               try {
                   final Uri imageUri = data.getData();
                   final InputStream imageStream = getActivity().getContentResolver().openInputStream(imageUri);
                   final Bitmap selectedImage = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(imageStream);
                   imageButton.setImageBitmap(selectedImage);
               } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                   e.printStackTrace();
               }

           }
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: hi @damian so thanks very much for the code but for some reason im getting an error on the getActivity method and only that part, should it be something else?